# Changing SRID of existing data in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

While importing my shapefile data to PostGIS, I did not select the proper Projection.

How do I now change the SRID of the data, without transforming the Coordinates?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

There is a single line function which does this for you. Just use the following SQL query:

```
select UpdateGeometrySRID('Schema Name', 'mytable', 'the_geom', newSRID) ;
```

But, if you are like me, you would be interested in the low level, miniature steps. Logically speaking, the above function is equivalent to the following four step process:

1. In the geometry_columns table, update the SRID to the required value.
2. Drop the contraint on the table, by using the following SQL statement

   `ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom;`
3. Update the SRID'd of the geometry by using the following SQL statement

   `UPDATE mytable SET the_geom  = ST_SetSRID(the_geom, newSRID);`
4. Add the contraint back by using the following SQL statement

   `ALTER TABLE mytable`

   `ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = (newSRID));`

Comment: See http://postgis.org/docs/ST_SetSRID.html for more info and links

Comment: I only use this "UPDATE mytable SET the_geom  = ST_SetSRID(the_geom, newSRID);"

Comment: @MdAmiruzzamanThis question is from the 1.x version of PostGIS, where the `geometries_columns` table was used; Now with 2.x, with this table not being used, you don't need to go via such a long process, but if you have constraint on your table, then that needs to be updated as well

Comment: UpdateGeometrySRID don't work if you have view on table. you need drop all views using your table before update geometry and them recreate all your views

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html -- link has moved

Answer (score 20):

With PostGIS 2.x, geometry columns typically use typmods like `geometry(Point, 1234)`. For these you can use [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) to directly modify the geometry column type in one step.

For example, to set the SRID of `geom` in `mytable` to WGS84, use [ST_SetSRID](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ALTER COLUMN geom
    TYPE geometry(Point, 4326)
    USING ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326);
```

Note that this will only alter the SRID, but not transform the coordinate data.

Comment: With a trivial change, this will also work with **geography** columns, which `UpdateGeometrySRID` does not support.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE public.kltask ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point, 4326) USING ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326);
```