# How to fix incorrect SRID of the geometry column?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, srid

I've been told to use AddGeometryColumn to properly add a column with correct/preferred SRID. however I wonder if it's possible to fix/change the current column instead of adding a new?
If there's no other way but to use this function should I remove the previous column?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [UpdateGeometrySRID](https://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html).

If you are just correcting a mistake, that's fine.  If not you also need to use ST_Transform (the documentation explains this).

Also see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/how-to-change-the-srid-of-exisisting-data-in-postgis).