# QGIS with CH1903/LV03 and WGS84 layers

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, qgis-2

I have a few CH1903/LV03 layers (lake, river and the country border of Switzerland) and a layer in WGS84 (two points of two cities, Vaduz and Bregenz).

On-the-fly-transformation is activated but Vaduz (Liechtenstein) and Bregenz (Austria) are still shown in Switzerland. Data source is a PostGIS database. Any idea why?

Comment: You may try to change the SRID of the layer with those two cities, using this link:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/how-to-change-the-srid-of-exisisting-data-in-postgis

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, or make sample data available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unsure which dataset is correct, you can set project CRS to EPSG:3857 and add Openstreetmap background with the Openlayers plugin:

[image]

I have added a grid in CH1903/LV03, while the points are saved in WGS84.