# ST_Transform not converting from utm to lat/lon

Tags: postgis, postgresql

This line:

```
ST_AsText(ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326))
```

Returns the "coordinates" as utm coordinates. Although, I thought ST_Transform was supposed to convert the coordinates from utm to lat/lon. I found a tutorial where the behavior I need is shown in an example: http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/projection.html

Is there any reason why it would not be doing this?

Comment: do you have a srid set on your geometry?

Comment: @atlefren Using Find_SRID() it returns 4326

Comment: It may be the_geom is not registered as UTM coordinates, so the transform is presuming there is no transform necessary and just giving you back the coordinates you put in.

Comment: @DPierce Is there an easy way to update my geometry so it registers as UTM? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: check out http://postgis.org/docs/ST_SetSRID.html

Comment: If you are sure that the coordinates are in UTM, but the Spatial references is set up incorrectly, have a look at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/

Comment: What does SELECT ST_SRID(the_geom) tell you your SRID is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I guess the all the geometries in my database were set to the wrong SRIDs. The geometries had SRIDs of 4326 when they should have been 3400, and this is why ST_Transform wasn't doing anything.

This is the code that ended up giving me what I wanted:

```
ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(the_geom, 3400), 4326)))
```