# What is the correct (QGIS) syntax for a masked PostQIS spatial query?

Tags: qgis, postgis, ubuntu, spatial-query

What is the correct syntax if I want to query a masked region from PostGIS from inside QGIS ?

The data is from "planet_osm_poly" (imported via osm2pgsql) and I'd like to use a polygon from a different table (table=e2e_buffers with name=corridor01) of the same database as mask of the spatial query.

Answer (score 1):

I seam to have [found](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) the answer to my own question, using the following SQL from within QGIS using the PostGIS-SQL-Editor:

`SELECT clipped.* 
FROM (SELECT pol.*, (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(corridor.geom,4326), ST_Transform(pol.way,4326)))).geom As clipped_geom
FROM buffer_ger AS corridor
    INNER JOIN planet_osm_line AS pol
    ON ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(corridor.geom,4326), ST_Transform(pol.way,4326)))  As clipped
    WHERE (
        (ST_Dimension(clipped.clipped_geom) = 1)
        AND ((osm_id > -70000) AND (osm_id < -60000))
        )
;`

Please note, that the `AND ((osm_id...` line in the end was only added to reduce query time while testing.

Additionally, I'll instantly start to convert all my basic / general tables to the same SRID ([How to change the SRID of exisisting data in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/how-to-change-the-srid-of-exisisting-data-in-postgis)) - this should avoid a lot of headaches and speed up things (no need of `ST_Transform`).
When trying to find a way to clip, I always expected PostGIS to internally recognize and deal with different SRIDs.

Sorry, if my question did bore some of you :-/