# Changing projection of PostGIS data?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis-2.0, utm, osm2pgrouting

I have exported osm data using osm2pgrouting in the database, it has SRID 4326. I want to change projection of all the tables created to a particular SRID in UTM. 
I read the post [FIrst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34612/how-to-change-the-srid-of-exisisting-data-in-postgis) and [Second](http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html), but these are only changing SRID withour transforming the coordinates. I am using the command

```
select UpdateGeometrySRID('Schema Name', 'mytable', 'the_geom', newSRID) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function used in `UpdateGeometrySRID` is `st_setsrid` instead of `st_transform`.

`st_setsrid` just sets the srid value without changing the coordinates. Since there is no function for looping tables to transform projection in PostGIS according to [updateGeometrySRID function](http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html). 
I suggest you to write a script in python to execute it:
Firstly execute to get the table names: 

`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='Schema Name'`
 
And then, for each table_name, you can execute:

`ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry USING ST_Transform(geom,newsrid);`