# Changing Coordinate System of Existing Table in GeoPackage

Tags: coordinate-system, geopackage

While writing some data to a GeoPackage, I set the wrong Coordinate System.

The Actual Coordinates are in a Particular UTM System, but the Table has been set as having data in EPSG:4326.

How do I now change the SRID of the data, without transforming the Coordinates?

I want to do the same thing as [Changing SRID of existing data in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34612) but for a GeoPackage.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix it using `ogrinfo` or `sqlite3` by running the following for `ogrinfo`. You will need to replace ocurences of `3857` by your own SRID code and `my_table_name` ocurences with your own table name too

```
# Work well because only one geometry column for table name
ogrinfo my.gpkg \
       -sql "UPDATE gpkg_geometry_columns SET srs_id = 3857 WHERE table_name = 'my_table_name'" \
       --config OGR_GPKG_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK OFF
# Dialect SQLite to get the SetSRID function available
ogrinfo my.gpkg -dialect SQlite -sql "UPDATE my_table_name set geom = SetSRID(geom, 3857)"
```

and with `sqlite3` command line:

```
sqlite3 my.gpkg "UPDATE gpkg_geometry_columns SET srs_id = 2154 WHERE table_name = 'my_table_name'"
sqlite3 my.gpkg "select load_extension('mod_spatialite');UPDATE my_table_name set geom = SetSRID(geom, 3857);"
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: Back up your data beforehand.

In QGIS open the Processing Toolbox and go to Vector General > Assign projection.

Select that layer and assign the correct projection.

Leave the output as [Create temporary layer].

Run the tool and make sure the output is correct.

Remove the original layer and overwrite it with the output (only if you have made a backup), or else save the output as a new layer in the geopackage.